# reduce vector length in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, vector, angle

How do i reduce the length of a vector when i have 2 point pairs without changing the angle of the vector (and if possible without calculating it before to speed things up).

Lets say i have a `P1 = (100,100)` and `P2 = (150, 100)` and i want to change the length of it so that the angle keeps the same, e.g. `ResultPoint = (135,100)`.

The ways i tried to solve it always ended up with some false angles. 
In the above example i would get a `ResultPoint = (135,90)` instead of `135,100`.

Comment: Just normalize the points. Like in your example, if your points are `(100, 100) and (150, 100)`, then a division by 10 would give the points `(10, 10) and (15, 10)`; the vector maintains the same direction with diminished magnitude.

Comment: if i understand it right then what you say is a little bit different. its right that it would keep the angle as before. but i dont want as result the Points `(10,10)` or `(15,10)`, i want a Point that is `(135,100)`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. A **vector** can either be represented as **two points that form the line of the vector** or **one point and the origin of the respective coordinate system, thereby getting the aforementioned line**.. You have **P1** and **P2**. If you want to change the length of the line connecting these two, refer to my previous comment. I fail to see how a **line** can be shortened to a **point**.

Comment: Im sorry if it was not that clear! The final vector should then pointing from `P1 = (100,100)` to `ResultPoint = (135,100)` and not to for example to `ResultPoint = (135,90)`

Comment: This example is a bit redundant since there is no slope change; let's make it interesting: what is your expected result would be if the points in question are `(100,100) & (150,200)`?

Comment: for example `112,124` or any other point on the line between  `(100,100) ` & `(150,200)` as long as it has the same angle

Comment: So, you basically want the same starting point. In that case, just put in `y = [(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)]*[x - x1] + y1` (in reference to the **point-slope** formula) and you can get all the points that you want. {P1 = (x1,y1); P2 = (x2,y2)}

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You can simply get its **middle point**. If that's not short enough, then you can get the **middle point of the middle point. ...** Until it fits your goal.

By getting the middle point, you're guaranteed that the point will not change the angle as it's always on the line.

---

**Edit:** You can also achieve your goal by computing its [**unit vector**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) (i.e. `length=1`).